# Как заставить перебор вписывать все выбранные значения в textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        List<string> Perebor(GroupBox groupBox)
        {
            List<string> value = new List<string>();
            foreach (Control control in groupBox.Controls)
            {
                if (control.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                {
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;
                    if (checkBox.Checked == true)
                        value.Add(checkBox.Text);
                }
                else if (control.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
                {
                    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)control;
                    if (radioButton.Checked == true)
                        value.Add(radioButton.Text);
                }
            }
            return value;
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (string text in Perebor(groupBox1))
            { textBox1.Text = text; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textBox1.Text = text;
```

в этой строке вы полностью перезаписываете значение, чтобы не терять то что там уже есть - используйте конкатенацию, например, так:

```
textBox1.Text += text + ";";
```

обратите внимание, я добавил еще и запись разделителя (точку с запятой), вы можете убрать его или использовать любой другой разделитель (может вам больше подойдет перевод строки)

Ну и имейте ввиду, что доступ к контролам довольно медленный, поэтому имеет смысл собрать строку в локальную переменную, а поместить значение в свойство контрола один раз в самом конце:

```
string result = "";
foreach (string text in Perebor(groupBox1))
    result += text + ";";
textBox1.Text = result;
```

Ну и, конечно, стандартная рекомендация, для конкатенации строк использовать `StringBuilder`, а не `string`.

Comment: Премного благодарен. Все работает :)